# pac4j for jee - is it possible to load external properties file instead of hardcode config in the implementation of ConfigFactory

Tags: jakarta-ee, openid-connect, saml-2.0, pac4j

I find out the official demo about the pac4j for JEE: jee-pac4j-demo in github (https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-demo)

The configuration for each Authentication mechanisms have defined in the org.pac4j.demo.jee.DemoConfigFactory, refer to the picture below:
[org.pac4j.demo.jee.DemoConfigFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8rTU.png)

However, many configs are hardcode in the ConfigFactory which is not flexible, is it any ways to define those configs in a property file such as oidc.properties / samls.properties, then we can load these properties and set to the ConfigFactory in order to adapt to diff environment (dev/sit/uat/prod).

Expect to define configs in external property file(s) such as oidc.properties / samls.properties, then we can load these properties and set to the ConfigFactory instead of hardcode configs in the implementation of ConfigFactory

Answer (score 0):

You can of course implement your own loading of properties in the `DemoConfigFactory` via the loading of a `java.util.Properties` component.

But you also have many other options:

- use the `pac4j-config` module
- move to a CDI model: https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-cdi-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/pac4j/demo/jee/SecurityConfig.java / https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-cdi-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/pac4j/demo/jee/WebConfig.java
- use Spring **without** Spring MVC: https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-demo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L14 / https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-demo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L59 (use of `DelegatingFilterProxy`)
- use Spring **with** Spring MVC: https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j

Comment: how can I use pac4j-config in the jee-pac4j-demo, I don't want to introduce the spring framework into the old application. I cannot find any sample for that.

Comment: You need to import the dependency and use the `PropertiesConfigFactory` component. It must be built from a map of String/String and then you call `build`. So you must first load the properties before turning it into a map and passing it to the `PropertiesConfigFactory`. Doc is missing here, see: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/5.7.x/pac4j-config/src/test/java/org/pac4j/config/client/PropertiesConfigFactoryTests.java